# Map string with regular expressions using some delimeter

Tags: python, regex, string, list, csv

Below is my input and I want the output as shown. There are 6 parameters separated by $$$.

Basically we have a csv file each line is having 6 different values as, Project Key, Jmp Issue, Summary, Updated time, Created time, Comments. First value will either be AGCSPSR or AGCSRNA Second value will again start will AGCS and end with some number (AGCSRNA-333). Third value will always be some comment fourth value will be time and date (2021-10-28T11:46:51Z) fifth will again be time and date last will be some string.

[IN]:

```
AGCSRNA AGCSRNA-333 WriteOff trx GL_MVMNT_TYP must be 101 2021-10-28T11:46:51Z 2021-09-30T09:36:04Z EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM;
```

[OUTPUT]:

```
AGCSRNA$$$AGCSRNA-333$$$WriteOff trx GL_MVMNT_TYP must be 101$$$2021-10-28T11:46:51Z$$$2021-09-30T09:36:04Z$$$EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM;
```

Comment: What are the rules for how we know where to put the `$$$` delimiters?

Comment: Edit your question and include this information.

Comment: Basically we have a csv file each line is having 6 different values as, 
Project Key, Jmp Issue, Summary, Updated time ,Created time ,Comments.  
First value will either be AGCSPSR or AGCSRNA  

Second value will again start will AGCS and end with some number(AGCSRNA-333) 
Third value will always be some comment
fourth value will be time and date (2021-10-28T11:46:51Z)
fifth will again be time and date 
last will be some string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here we go... Sample python code:

```
import re
regex = r"(AGCSPSR|AGCSRNA)\s+(AGCS.+?\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(\.\d+)?.+)\s+(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(\.\d+)?.+)\s+(.+);"
test_str = "AGCSRNA AGCSRNA-333 WriteOff trx GL_MVMNT_TYP must be 101 2021-10-28T11:46:51Z 2021-09-30T09:36:04Z EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM;"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
for match in matches:
    print('$$$'.join(match))
```

Outut :
`AGCSRNA$$$AGCSRNA-333$$$WriteOff trx GL_MVMNT_TYP must be 101$$$2021-10-28T11:46:51Z$$$$$$2021-09-30T09:36:04Z$$$$$$EXAMPLE@EXAMPLE.COM`

Tip last semicolon is excluded from regex. If want to include that, please use below regex:
`AGCSPSR|AGCSRNA)\s+(AGCS.+?\d+)\s+(.+?)\s+(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(\.\d+)?.+)\s+(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(\.\d+)?.+)\s+(.+)`